# No MediaTypeFormatter error when trying to parse ReadAsFormDataAsync result in WebAPI

Tags: json, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, httprequest

I have created a WebAPI project to help capture statements from a TinCan learning course but I am having extreme difficulty in retrieving any of the Request payload details. Within this payload I pass the whole statement that I am trying to capture but upon trying to read using:

```
var test = Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result.ToString();
```

I get the following error message:

**No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'FormDataCollection' from content with media type 'application/json'.**

I have tried Converting the result object to JSON to overcome this problem but it has not been any use. Do I need to configure json somewhere in the configuration? I have tried adding

```
var appXmlType = config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.FirstOrDefault(t => t.MediaType == "application/xml");
        config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Remove(appXmlType);
```

and also:

```
var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        config.Formatters.Insert(0, jsonFormatter);
```

to my WebApiConfig.cs file as answered in another question of how to return json but I cannot seem to pass this error. I have also set config.formatter to accept application/json but this also has not worked

**CONTROLLER CODE**

```
public void Put([FromBody]string statementId)
    {   
        var test = Request.Content.ReadAsFormDataAsync().Result;

        System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "/xAPI/PUT has been called", System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
```

Comment: Posting your controller code would help.

Answer (score 5):

From the error message you have provided, it seems like request content is in `application/json`.  `ReadAsFormDataAsync()` can only read content of type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

In this case, you can use `ReadAsAsync<>` if you have the type you want to be deserialized defined or simply use `ReadAsStringAsync<>` if you just want to read the content as a `string`.